# Block search engines to display ads of my page

Tags: web-crawler, google-ads-api, yandex

I want to disallow crawlers of google/yandex/bing (all other prominent search engines) to display ads of my website. ( I know this might sound insane, but please understand the confidentiality). Someone else is bidding for my webpage against me, and I dont want to encourage such behaviour.

Basically I dont want any ads about my webpage. One way that I think it is possible is to disallow their bots in robot.txt. Will this work? If yes, how can I get a list of UA for all major players and all their adbots.

If not, what are solutions do I have ?

Answer (score 0):

There is programs as AdBlock or similar you could add to your browser to avoid adds in a specific navigator.

Avoiding adds of your website, that's a different thing,  you should exclude your page for your marketing contract with Google.

I don't see this related to the crawlers.